# Laravel admin route is not handel by laravel 6

Tags: laravel, apache

my  `web.php` file

```php
Route::get('admin', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

it's not working

error im getting in blow page
[image]

it's showing apache2 error can anybody know what is wrong.

it should handel by laravel right .?

---

**i m using**

**Laravel 6**

**mysql 5.7.29**

**Ubuntu 18.4**

---

`php artian serve` gives me again diffrent error show in below

[image]

Thanks

Comment: check your port properly or you can run using `php artisan serve --port=8080`

Comment: @Hamelraj not working please check in you system

Comment: i installed laravel 6 already its working fine without any issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that it is showing 403 Forbidden is most probably because apache is trying to directory-list /admin folder but it is prohibited to do so.

I think in laravel directory `public` folder have the `admin` folder name. Please check.

If the `admin` folder exists rename folder name.

So the solution is to make sure that you do not have a folder 'admin' inside `public` folder.

Comment: Thanks for great explanation, i have assets in `public/admin` folder

Comment: @KamleshPaul So now you need to change route name or folder name right.

Comment: sure will do that

Answer (score 0):

you should visit `/admin` to view the page, remove public

Comment: `Not Found
The requested resource /admin was not found on this server.` this error i m getting by this

Answer (score 0):

You should add port 80 in your url

```
localhost:80/project_folder/public/admin
```

or you if you have xampp folder you can edit virtual host document root in vhost file pointed to your project folder

```
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/project/public"
```

so you can just use

```
localhost/admin
```